# Cefsharp: how to get value from settings?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Before opening the browser, Cefsharp initializes the settings.
Is it possible to get something like a list of these same settings programmatically? For example in a message box?

```
public void InitializeChromium()
{
    settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "127.0.0.1:8080");
    // ...etc
}
```

Example:

```
MessageBox.Show(settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Values.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettings_CefCommandLineArgs.htm) is a `IDictionary<string, string>` so something like the following may do the job.

```
var myArgs = string.Join(", ", settings.CefCommandLineArgs
        .Select( s => $"{s.Key}={s.Value}"));
```

You may want to prettify it for settings with no values (flags).

Answer (score -1):

```
string.Join(", ", settings.CefCommandLineArgs)
```

Work for me...